# Debugging in the subchild process doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, autocad, mbunit, gallio

I write the plugins for AutoCAD. But it is unpossible to write the unit tests for AutoCAD plugins as the MS Visual Studio tests. Because they must work in the acad.exe process.

For solving its problem I use [Gallio](https://code.google.com/p/mb-unit/). It has own plugin for testing of AutoCAD plugins.

So, when I press the F5 key in Visual Studio, it runs the `Gallio.Echo.exe` with the necessary arguments. Then `Gallio.Echo.exe` launches the `acad.exe` and loads my tests into this process. So my IDE are connected to the `Gallio.Echo.exe`, but my code are working in the acad.exe.

[image]

All works fine, but I have one desire: I want in my code the working break points in the `DEBUG` mode. Now they are ignored.

Can I solve this problem?

P.S. I use a remote debugging, if it is important.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved.
In the Gallio settings I have set the "Attach to an existing AutoCAD process" option. Also for MS Visual Studio project (the project with my Gallio tests) I have set the usual settings like for the usual AutoCAD plugin (F5 key pressing runs the acad.exe).

So I press F5, AutoCAD has launched and I launch my BAT file - it launches the Gallio.Echo.exe with the necessary arguments. All works fine: the break points works in my Gallio tests now.

So it is possible to launch the tests via the *.BAT file only (i.e. without break points), and, if it is necessary, via the *.BAT file + MS Visual Studio (i.e. with the working break points).